# What is the difference between these two given sums?

Tags: calculus, summation

What is the difference between this: $\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i+9x*i)$  and $\sum_{i=0}^n x[x^i+9i+9]$ ?
So far I know that the first terms are not different.

The first term of the $\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i+9x*i)$  is $\ x+9x$.

And the first term for $\sum_{i=0}^n x[x^i+9i+9]$ is $\ x*x^0+9x*0+9x$ which equals $\ x+9x$.

What I'm unable to figure out is the difference between the sums still. I think that the last term of the first sum is $\ x^n+9x(n)$ and the last term of the second term is $\ x^{n+1}+9n(x)+9x$. But I don't know if that is correct, or even if it is correct where to go from this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started: The second sum is $\sum_{i=0}^n (x^{i+1}+9x(i+1)).$ Notice that if $0\leq i<n$, then the $i$th term of that sum equals the $(i+1)$st term of the first sum in your question. So some cancellation occurs in the difference...

**Added:** You already observed what I said in the case $i=0$: The $0$th term in the second sum is $x+9x$, and the $1$st term in the first sum is $x+9x$. So in the difference, these terms cancel. For $i=1$, the $1$st term in the second sum is $x^2+9x(2)$, while the $2$nd term in the first sum is $x^2+9x(2)$. So these terms cancel in the difference. For $i=2$, the $2$nd term in the second sum is $x^3+9x(3)$ while the $3$rd term in the first sum is $x^3+9x(3)$. So these cancel, etc. Of course this doesn't go on indefinitely. There is one term in the second sum leftover.

Comment: I don't get how it cancels though. I feel like the 9x prevents It from canceling. Please tell me if I'm thinking incorrectly.

Comment: I added some more details. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Ah now I get what you mean. That does help. Thanks